# Why does a private struct defined in a .h require a scope in a return type in the .cpp file?

Tags: c++, namespaces, private-members

Header looks like this:

```
namespace A {
class A {
  private:
    struct B  {
      int x;
    };

    B foo();
};
}
```

And my .cpp looks like this

```
namespace A {
   A::B A::foo() { //implement }
}
```

Why can't I just do :

```
B A::foo() {//implement}
```

If `B` is scoped inside `A` in the .h file, why do we need `A::B` in the cpp file?
Wouldn't the fact that we are already in the `A` namespace be sufficient to not have to define the `A::B`? I understand that `B` is private to `A`, but does that really matter in the case of namespaces?

Comment: What happens if you include another header that has an unscoped B? There are reasons for this being strict.

Comment: I looked at the code again and you're right. there does seem to be the class within the namespace of the same name.

Comment: There are two different As in there. Perhaps not giving a member of a namespace the same name as the namespace could reduce some of the confusion.

Answer (score 8):

Until you reach `A::foo` in the function definition you are in the the scope of where the function is begin defined.  Since you are not in the class scope, `B` is not in scope and results in a compiler error.

You have to use `A::` to tell the compiler where `B` is located.  Once you reach `A::foo` you are now in the scope of `A` again and it is not needed.  One thing you can do is to use a trailing return type to put the return in the class scope like

```
auto A::foo() -> B { ... }
```

Comment: Would this also be the case if B were a public member type and for the same reason?

Comment: @Skorpius Yes.  The accessibility doesn't matter here.  What matters is the `B` is defined in `A` so you must refer to it as `A::B` outside of the scope of `A`.

Answer (score 0):

`B` is an inner type of the `A` class. When the compiler encounters `B` in the `B A::foo() { ... }` definition, it hasn't seen `A::foo()` yet to establish that `B` should be looked for in the scope of `A`, and not as some other `B` that may already be in scope from elsewhere. So you have to explicitly qualify `B` as `A::B` at that stage of the definition.

That is not the case if you use `B` as a parameter instead:

```
void A::foo(B &b) { ... }
```

Or as the return type for an `auto` return value:

```
auto A::foo() -> B { ... }
```

In both cases, `A::foo()` is encountered first to establish the scope needed for the compiler to figure out on its own that `B` refers to `A::B`.

Answer (score 0):

> If B is scoped inside A in the .h file, why do we need A::B in the cpp file?

But `B` is *not* scoped inside `::A`. `B` is scoped inside `::A::A`. So, even when you're within the namespace `::A`, you need to qualify `A::B` which is inside the class `A` (fully qualified as `::A::A`) because `B` is not declared within the namespace `::A`. Being in the namespace `::A` means that you don't need to qualify `B` as `A::A::B`.

> I understand that B is private to A, but does that really matter in the case of namespaces?

The access specifier doesn't matter. The scope in which the class is declared does matter. Classes have a scope, and nested classes are declared within that scope.